# Lumen using Graph API with socialite

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, lumen, laravel-socialite

I am trying to get my app to redirect to the Facebook login page so I can access thee Graph API endpoints.

In bootstrap/app.php  have

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
// $app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);

class_alias(Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class, 'Socialite');

$app->register(Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class);
```

My controller is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Facebook;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;


class FacebookController extends Controller
{
 public function redirectToProvider(Request $request)
{
    return Socialite::with('facebook')->redirect();
}

 public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
  {
    //here you hadle input user data
    $user = Socialite::with('facebook')->user();
  }
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('facebook','App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('callback','App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

My composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.6",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.2",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    }
}
```

All posts I have seen use the config/servcies.php or config/app.php files however I cannot and these files in lumen

Unsure if this is helpful but  get these errors when  go to the http://local/admin/facebook/login page

```
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/facebook/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php:230
  at Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array(0))
     (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/facebook/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php:170)
  at Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(object(Request))
     (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/facebook/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php:426)
  at Laravel\Lumen\Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure))
     (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/facebook/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php:172)
  at Laravel\Lumen\Application->dispatch(null)
     (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/facebook/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Concerns/RoutesRequests.php:109)
  at Laravel\Lumen\Application->run()
     (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/facebook/public/index.php:28)
```

Comment: You should go and reset your app secret via the app dashboard now, because by exposting yours in the code above, you have given everyone reading this a valid, non-expiring app access token to your app.

Comment: _“but get these errors”_ - what you’ve currently shown there, does not even contain an actual error message, it just shows the trace of where one occurred.